# haskell stack - random numbers package

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

We are new users trying to use random numbers in a new stack project, but cannot `import System.Random`. It doesn't seem to be in the curated set(?)

We've got a new stack project setup as in the user manual. We've edited the cabal file putting `random` in library build depends, and later put `- random-1.1` in the yaml extra-deps. However after stack build it reaches Main.hs but then fails with

```
Failed to load interface for System.Random
It is a member of the hidden package random-1.1
```

How do we get a simple working random package in there.

Comment: Main.hs is probably the executable, not the library, so you’d have to add `random` to the executable’s dependencies.

Comment: Tangential note: you can find whether e.g. *random* is in Stackage by visiting https://www.stackage.org/package/random . Doing it the other way around, a full list of packages in e.g. lts-7.14 lies at https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.14 .

Comment: Tangential note II: `random` is a really bad RNG.  Use something else, like `entropy`, `drbg`, `tf-random`, etc.

Comment: Yes @Alexis , putting random in the executable dependencies does just the trick. Thanks for that, and other tips too.